# How to refer to an array in a Cloud Function

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Below is the javascript function that runs on my Angular JS Webapp:

```
$scope.pick = [0,1,2,4,5,];
$scope.players = admin.database().ref("Player").child("playerweek8").orderByChild("id");

$firebaseArray(orderedPlayers)
        .$loaded(function(loadedPlayers) {
        var normalizedPlayers = loadedPlayers.reduce(function(acc, next) { acc[next.id] = next; return acc; }, {});
        var selectedPlayers = $scope.pick.map(function(num){
            return normalizedPlayers[num];
        });
        $scope.players = selectedPlayers;
```

However, when I tried to transfer the function to y firebase database Cloud function as follows:

```
exports.sync = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

    admin.database().ref('users').once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
       var updates = {};
       const orderedPlayers = admin.database().ref("Player").child("playerweek8").orderByChild("id");
       var normalizedPlayers = orderedPlayers.reduce(function(acc, next) { acc[next.id] = next; return acc; }, {});



       snapshot.forEach(function(userSnapshot) {
           var users = userSnapshot.val();
           var selection = users.selection;
           updates[`/users/${userSnapshot.key}/week1`] = 10;


           var players = selection.map(function(num){
                return normalizedPlayers[num];
            }); 
updates[`/users/${userSnapshot.key}/week2`] =   players; 
       });
       admin.database().ref().update(updates).then(function() {
           res.send('it worked');
       });
   });
});
```

However, I keep getting the error code:`TypeError: orderedPlayers.reduce is not a function`

Is the issue that orderedPlayers is not a returning the player array at `admin.database().ref("Player").child("playerweek8").orderByChild("id");` ?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the API docs, [orderByChild()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Query#orderByChild) is a method on Query that returns another Query.  It doesn't contain any results.

If you want the results of the query, you'll have to call [once()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Query#once) on it, then use the resulting snapshot to iterate the results.